# convert unicode ucs4 into utf8

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a value like u'\U00000958' being returned back from a database and I want to convert this string to `utf8`.  I try something like this:

```
cp = u'\\U00000958'
value = cp.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
print 'Value: " + value
```

I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

What can I do to properly convert this value?

More Detail.  I'm in 2.7.10 which uses ucs2.

Comment: Does `cp = u'\\U00000958'`? Maybe you could try `unicode('utf-8', cp.decode('unicode-escape'))` Your code works for me, strangely, and I get `Value: '\xe0\xa5\x98'`

Comment: decoded = unicode( 'utf-8', cp.decode('unicode-escape')) gets me the same error

Comment: See more detail above:  @PeterWang

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: On the encode.  No error if I remove the encode.

Comment: Any ideas?  @PM2Ring

Comment: Info added forgot to send an at.  @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: 2.7 unicode uses either 2 or 4 byte per char depending on the OS and build.

Comment: You example works (although it's not good practice to decode a Unicode and won't work in Py3). Please provide a proper [mcve]. `decoded = unicode( 'utf-8', cp.decode('unicode-escape')) ` is garbage. Please check the arguments order.

Answer (score 0):

For unicode issues, it often helps to specify python 2 versus python 3, and also how one came to get a particular representation.

It is not clear from the first sentence what the actual value is, as opposed to how it is displayed.  It is unclear if the `value like u'\\U00000958'` is a 1 char unicode string, a 10 char unicode string, a 14 char (ascii) byte string, or something else.  Use of `len` and `type` can be used to be sure of what you have.

By trying to decode `cp`, you are implying that you know that `cp` is bytes, but what encoding?  The error message says that it is not ascii bytes. 0xe0 is a typical start byte for utf-8 encoding.  The following interaction

```
>>> s = "u'\\U00000958'"
>>> se = eval(s)
>>> se
u'\u0958'
>>> se.encode(encoding='utf-8')
'\xe0\xa5\x98'
>>>
```

suggests to me that cp, starting with \xe0 is 3 utf-8 encoded bytes and that `u'\\U00000958'` is an evaluable representation of its unicode decoding.

Comment: The version was quickly added to the question before this response was sent.  Maybe timing issue.  So 2.7 with ucs2.  I am testing unicode support and the value is stored as \U00000958 in the database BUT is returned as u'\\U00000958'. So first part removes the escape.  The actual character is also stored in the DB and I'm trying up convert the \U version to a UTF-8 for comparison.  It is in this format since Python 2.7 has other issues.  Which are to long to post here.  This format suggested on another post.

Comment: Also cp in my code example is NOT wrapped in double quotes.  Assume that I'm pulling the value from a dictionary or I coded it without the double quotes.